# Difference between define and define*

Tags: scheme, gambit

Forgive my ignorance, but what is the difference between these two:

```
(define blah)
(define* blah)
```

? Unfortunately Google ignores the asterisks character.

Comment: Can you post a more detailed piece of working code? Or where did you find code using the `define*` special form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SRFI 89](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-89/srfi-89.html) was written by Gambit's author, so it's only fair to assume that Gambit's `define*` does what that document says. :-)

In other words, it's syntactic sugar over `lambda*` (as described in SRFI 89) rather than `lambda`.

Answer (score 0):

In the (rather extensive) [documentation](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/doc/gambit-c.html) of Gambit Scheme there is no mention of a `define*` special form; it might be some procedure, definition, macro or special form found only in the piece of code where you saw it. You should post a link referencing the source of the code where `define*` is being used.

Answer (score 0):

A little more context for the question would be nice.

Sometimes the * just means that the form does something extra.
My guess is therefore that define* works as ordinary define,
but at the same time does something extra. This extra could
be automatically exporting the name from a module.

This definition was found in the Racket ffi-lib illustrates
this principle:

```
(define-syntax define*
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (name . args) body ...)
     (begin (provide name) (define (name . args) body ...))]
    [(_ name expr)
     (begin (provide name) (define name expr))]))
```